# VisualStudio отсутствуют соответствующие операторы в Vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Создал `Vector`

```
#ifndef KONTODATA_H
#define KONTODATA_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct KontoData
{
    short iD;
    string Name;
    string Vorname;
    int KN;
    int BLZ;
    float KS;
    float dispo;
};

#endif // KONTODATA_H
```

Пытаюсь загрузить в него данные

```
ifstream Bankdaten;
    Bankdaten.open("BankDaten.txt");

    KontoData* k = new KontoData();
    if (Bankdaten.good())
    {
        int anzahlDaten;
        Bankdaten >> anzahlDaten;
        for (int i = 0; i < anzahlDaten; i++)
        {
            Bankdaten >> k->Name; //ошибка
        }
    }
```

В `.txt` присутствуют данные, подобие

```
Alex    Kiev    0022044865  70052060    5000    3000
```

На строке `Bankdaten >> k->Name;` показывает ошибку - `отсутствует оператор ">>", соответвующий этим операндам`, не пойму в чем проблема.

Comment: После     Bankdaten >> anzahlDaten;  файловый поток приводится в состояние fail, после чего невозможно ничего читать. Это происходит, потому что 
в начале файла нет обьекта целочисленного типа

Comment: Просто забыли сделать `#include <string>`. Очень часто этот вопрос всплывает.